# C++/CX How to create a BitmapImage from a buffer and buffer count

Tags: bitmap, count, buffer, bitmapimage, c++-cx

I use the mediaCapture with AddEffectsAsync in order to set a MFT on the camera. Using that MFT I was able to return back the data for each frame, from the MFT. Now The bitmap comes as a Nokia::Ghraphics::Imaging::Bitmap class.
In the following code, I take the size of the buffer and the buffer from it and send it to my application:

```
void TransformImage_NV12(
const D2D_RECT_U &rcDest,
_Inout_updates_(_Inexpressible_(2 * lDestStride * dwHeightInPixels)) BYTE *pDest,
_In_ LONG lDestStride,
_In_reads_(_Inexpressible_(2 * lSrcStride * dwHeightInPixels)) const BYTE *pSrc,
_In_ LONG lSrcStride,
_In_ DWORD dwWidthInPixels,
_In_ DWORD dwHeightInPixels,
IVector<IImageProvider^>^ providers)
{

    auto size = Windows::Foundation::Size(dwWidthInPixels, dwHeightInPixels);
    auto totalbytes = (int)dwHeightInPixels * (int)dwWidthInPixels * 3 / 2;

    Nokia::Graphics::Imaging::Bitmap^ m_BitmapToProcess = AsBitmapNV12(pSrc, (unsigned int)size.Width, (unsigned int)size.Height);

    BitmapImageSource^ source = ref new BitmapImageSource(m_BitmapToProcess);
    auto first = providers->GetAt(0);
    ((IImageConsumer^)first)->Source = source;

    auto last = providers->GetAt(providers->Size - 1);

    BitmapRenderer^ renderer = ref new BitmapRenderer(last, ColorMode::Yuv420Sp);

    auto renderOp = renderer->RenderAsync();
    auto renderTask = create_task(renderOp);

    renderTask.then([pDest, totalbytes](Nokia::Graphics::Imaging::Bitmap^ bitmap)
    {
        auto count = bitmap->Buffers->Length;
        unsigned char* data = FromIBuffer(bitmap->Buffers[0]->Buffer);
        CMFTWrapper::FrameData = data;
        CMFTWrapper::count = count;
        SetEvent(CMFTWrapper::FrameEvent());
        CopyMemory(pDest, data, totalbytes);
    }).wait();
}
```

Doing this I have a callback being called in my application:

```
void VideoCapturerSampleCallback(struct LmiVideoCapturer_* capturer, const LmiVideoFrame* videoFrame, LmiVoidPtr userData)
{
    App2::MainPage^ ctx = context;
    Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::MainView->CoreWindow->Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([ctx]()
    {          
        Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage^ bitmapImage =
        ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::BitmapImage();
        //TODO will need to create it from the buffer
        media->Source = bitmapImage;
}));
}
```

Here I have access to the Buffer and the count from the MFT, by using CMFTWrapper class, in which I have saved the data.
My question is how can I load this data inside my bitmapImage I created?
I found some codes showing me how to build aa bitmapImage, but most of them are in C# and I need to use C++/cx

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx).

With WriteableBitmap, you need to use IBufferByteAccess (include robuffer.h to get this definition):

```
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
auto xaml_image = ref new WriteableBitmap(width, height);

// Cast PixelBuffer to Object^, then to its underlying IInspectable interface.
Object^ obj = xaml_image->PixelBuffer;
ComPtr<IInspectable> insp(reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(obj));

// Query the IBufferByteAccess interface.
ComPtr<IBufferByteAccess> bufferByteAccess;
ThrowIfFailed(insp.As(&bufferByteAccess));

// Get native pointer to the buffer data.
byte* pixels = nullptr;
ThrowIfFailed(bufferByteAccess->Buffer(&pixels));

// TODO: copy image data in BGRA8 format into 'pixels' buffer
// memcpy_s(pixels, xaml_image->PixelBuffer->Capacity, data, width*height*4);

// Set final source
media->Source = xaml_image;
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer because I apparently did not read the question properly.

Have you seen the CameraPreviewImageSource btw? It uses MF under the hood, letting you process the camera preview stream.

Btw, there is now a version 2.0 of what is renamed the Lumia Imaging SDK. Upgrade the nuget package to get it.

Comment: Btw, there might be a sample published at some point on how to make an MFT that uses the Imaging SDK pipeline. Would that be of interest?